# Excel: How to use cell content to dynamically refer to other Excel files and sheets

Tags: excel, reference, excel-indirect

Say I am in Excel file "FileA", sheet "SheetA" and cell A1. In cell A2 and B2, I have text content FileB, FileC and in cell A3 and B3, I have text content SheetB and SheetC. Now I want to dynamically refer to FileB, SheetB, using reference to A2 and A3, instead of FileB and SheetB, how do I do that? thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).  Note that if you are referencing a different workbook, that different workbook *must* be open (it cannot reference closed workbooks).

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016

Comment: I can use Indirect to refer to a sheet with contents in cell, but not to a different file... and if i have to keep all files open, that is a bit too much...